# How to clean cloned input value?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with function "add new column". When it is pressed, a new column is added, but it has previous column values. How can I clean cloned input value?

My table looks like:

```
<tr>
<td><input style="width:80%" id="row_name2" type="text" name="option[0][]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

jquery:

```
var table = line.parentNode.parentNode;
        jQuery.each( jQuery('tbody tr',table) , function(i, obj){
            jQuery('td:eq('+(cols-2)+')',obj).after(
                jQuery('td:eq('+(cols-2)+')',obj).clone()

            );
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.find('input').val('')` after the `.clone()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are cloning something and you want to make sure the values are not part of the cloning, you want to have a process that is: `find target` -> `clone` -> `clear vals` -> `append`.

here's a simple (untested, trimmed from one I us) function for clearing the values in your `tr`

```
function clear_vals(tr){
   tr.find('input').val('');
   return tr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(Element).attr("name", "Your Name"); // is name of the column, not the displayed value.
```